# Primefaces Collector not Working the Second Time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, collections, primefaces

I have a dialog box with a collector in it; it works fine the first time but when I click cancel and reopen the dialog and try to add items to the collector nothing happens (the array list in the backing bean remains empty)

Here is the XHTML of the button the collector is nested in:

```
<p:commandButton value=" + " id="swimlaneInput"
    update="swimlaneInput @this, data @this" action="#{wall.reset}"
    style="border-color: #429491; background-color: #f3d7d8;">
    <p:collector value="#{wall.swimlane}" addTo="#{wall.swimlanes}"
        type="submit" />
    <p:resetInput target="swimlaneInput" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Here is the XHTML of the Cancel Button:

```
<p:commandButton id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"
    action="#{wall.cancel}" oncomplete="dialogWidget.hide()"
    style="border-color: #429491; background-color: #f3d7d8;" update="@all">
    <p:resetInput target="dialog" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Note: both the + button that adds strings to the collector and the cancel button are in the same form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the buttons from PrimeFaces buttons to JSF buttons (`<h:commandButton>`) seems to have fixed the problem